# How to model parent/child composite when the child is related to another class

Tags: object-oriented, composition

I don't know which is the correct way to model this requirement in OOD:
A device has many properties, each property has exactly one device parent.
There are a set of procedures and a specific procedure describe one or many
properties.

From the system I need to retrieve the list of all procedures, and
for each procedure the list of all the properties associated (referencing
also the parent device) i.e: procedure1-device1-propertyX, procedure1-device1-propertyY, procedure1-device2-propertyX.

One model could be:

[image]

In this way the procedure it's related with the child of the composite relationship Device-Property.

Another could be:

[image]

In this way a new relation class "MapDevicePropProcedure" is present and at runtime will store the references of the three objects.

Any advice on which is the best way to model this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: It might just be me, but this reads like a difficult puzzle :P Can you show some code as examples of what you mean, eg "A device has many properties, each property has exactly one device parent" is a device parent a class? Are "properties" the device properties or literally class properties?

Comment: In terms of your question in the title "*How to model parent/child composite when the child is related to another class*" -  Is the class related to the child class through inheritance or also composition? If the former and you now need to use something that is extended and tightly coupled, you might need to refactor to free it. If it's composition then why can't you just use that child class again in another place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two approaches are capturing different information.

In the former case, all procedures apply to all properties regardless of what device is involved.

In the latter, procedures only apply to device-property pairs.

Thus, if a property applies to many devices, but the procedure is restricted somehow by device or device-property pair, then the latter can represent that whereas the former cannot.

So, the decision should be based on which one properly models your domain.  The former is less restrictive, but may not capture what is needed as constraints for the domain.  Whereas the latter is more complex, in that more records will be needed to capture generality.